# Similar Questions pane visual bug

Tags: bug, status-declined, design

[image: Screanie]

The way the Similar Questions pane "writes over" the footer is not behavior I would expect. Is that correct behavior?

Comment: Declining for completeness sake - we are declining other duplicates...