# “Similar questions” scrolls down and covers other links

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Similar Questions pane visual bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105435/similar-questions-pane-visual-bug)

"Similar questions" should not move with the scrolling not only at SO but other [sites](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878/similar-questions-scrolls-down-and-covers-other-links) have this problem as well. This occurs with FF 11.0 under win7.

Steps:

1. press Ask Question button
2. Write title, question content and add tags
3. Scroll down

[image]
[image]